# Set maximum width of table by renewing commands

Tags: tables, xetex, pandoc, markdown

I am currently using a template that looks like this:

```
% -------------------------------------------------------
% Things for styling tables
% -------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{multirow,longtable,booktabs,tabu}
\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}
% Booktabs styling
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{1.5pt}% Thick top and bottom lines
\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{0.65ex}% Adjusted line spacing
\let\originaltoprule\toprule
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{tabu}
```

So my problems it that the tables produced by this setup ends up very close to the right margin of the page.

Is there a way to configure the table to either match to page width, or specify a hard limit in the above setup?

To produce the output I use `markdown` as input and output PDF using `Pandoc` and `xetex`.

Comment: It depends on how your table is coded. But first, I would recommend not using `tabu` as it is buggy and outdated. A better choice would be the package `tabularray` and its `tblr` or `longtblr` environment. It has the possibility of specifying the table width.

Comment: I guess my problem is also that the table is generated by Pandoc from markdown files.

Comment: Yes, I think pandoc doesn't have enough options for table generation. You may look at this to see if it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34077289/154252